# I have a .CSV file that contains dates and gms value for those dates. Is it possible to apply Linear Regression to this?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

Consider i have a .csv file that has two attributes that are dates and gms\revenue value for that date. Is it possible to apply Linear regression to predict the gms value for a particular date or does this come under time series regression analysis?I'm new to machine learning so any help would be appreciated.Thank you. [this is the csv file and it has around 1800 records. Dates are continuous.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wePy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Time series models will be able to find patterns in the revenue over time.
Regression models will predict the revenue given an input set of variables.

Since you have time as the only predictor variable, it would come under time-series analysis. You can still try to solve it using regression, but your prediction will just be a line (or any other polynomial curve) incresing or decreasing with time. It will not be able to capture the seasonality and lag-dependent trends which are common in time-series data.